# Transitioning from Mobile to Digital Camera Photography

Tags: digital, photography-basics, smartphone, travel

I've been passionately involved in mobile photography for the past two years and am now looking to expand my horizons into digital camera photography. As an international student in the UK, I'm working within a budget, so I'd appreciate any guidance on how to start this journey.

Key points I'm seeking advice on:

1. **Camera Selection**: What are some budget-friendly digital camera options that are suitable for a beginner yet offer a significant upgrade from smartphone photography? I prefer to shoot landscape, portraits andf mainly travel photography.
2. **Learning Resources**: Can you recommend any online resources, books, or courses that are particularly good for beginners in digital photography? I know basics of Adobe PS, but edit my smartphone pics on Snapseed/Picsart.
3. **UK Specific Tips**: Are there any UK-specific tips, especially in the west midlands region near Birmingham, such as shops for purchasing equipment, student discounts, or local photography communities I should be aware of?
4. **Skill Transition**: How can I best leverage my experience in mobile photography when transitioning to a digital camera?

Comment: Hi there. Shopping/recommendation questions are off-topic here. They don't help enough people, and the information goes out of date too quickly. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Also, restrict your questions to one question per post.

Comment: Ok, how should I modify my question?

Comment: See also: [Continue taking photos from smartphone or buy a camera to practice?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/89861) and [High end smartphone camera vs. high end compact camera for beginner?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/96742)

Comment: Thank you for the references, will check them.

Comment: To be honest, for the past 10 years or so, there have been no bad cameras released. The short (cynical?) answer is just buy any camera and get on with practicing.  Henri Cartier-Bresson famously said, "Your first 10,000 photos are your worst."

Comment: One strictly UK advice: take precautions about the moisture, UK seems to be quite wet country :)

Comment: This is a well-worded question even if it's split into multiple parts.

Comment: @NeuralNetNomad even though you would prefer an answer to all of your questions simultaneously you should split them into 4 questions because they are mostly independent. This improves usability of answers for other users of StackExchange. There is no limit on the amount of questions you ask if they are well-worded.

Comment: I have to say, I _don't_ think this is a good question (set). What's being asked here is either off-topic (shopping) or has been asked before. The site works best for specific photographic problems you are facing, not just links or pointers to other resources.

Comment: Thanks for all the inputs.